# Is there any way to access the array of objects properties in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to the react-native programming. What I find more difficult is accessing the array of objects in react-native. I'm working on a simple react-native app, I had made a localhost server request but in the server response, I'm getting the array of objects. I tried accessing those array of the object using normal JavaScript period operator. But, I don't allow us to access those Object.

> Property which I gonna access within the array of objects shown in below picture.
>   [image]

Here, I go with localhost server request

```
 export default class Gallery extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    fetch('http://139.162.27.183:8080/Eshiksha/org/'+this.props.orgId+'/branch/'+this.props.branchId+'/videourl/videourls', { 'method' : 'GET', 
          headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : this.props.auth
          }
     })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({ data: responseData });
      console.log(this.state.data.videoUrls[4]); // Using Remote JS Debugging i consoled out following array of object it's shown. But same code (this.state.data.videoUrls[4]) not being accessed within the render function.
    })
    .done();
  }

    render(){
        return(
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.state.data.videoUrls[4].eventName}</Text> // Here, I'm getting error which is shown below image
                  </View>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./school.jpg')} />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Within the react-native render() function I'm trying to access those array of objects within the server response data. Here, I'm getting the following error which is shown in below picture.
[image]

Please help me to find a solution to access those array of object property in react-native. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your render method is rendering the Views before your request. You should check if response is ready. You can check it. You can write log inside to render method.

Comment: How it could be done. Please help me

Comment: Look the answer. If it is work please select it to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should run. You first check if response ready inside the state.
If your response is ready you can change the state. Check the code.

```
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              data: [],
              isReady:false,  //create isReady on the state
            }     

        componentWillMount(){
                fetch('http://139.162.27.183:8080/Eshiksha/org/'+this.props.orgId+'/branch/'+this.props.branchId+'/videourl/videourls', { 'method' : 'GET', 
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' : this.props.auth
                      }
                 })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {
                  this.setState({ data: responseData, isReady:true}); //when response came change the status.
                })
                .done();
              }

            render(){
                const {isReady} = this.state; //check the state if response is ready render your scrollview
               if(isReady)
                return(
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={styles.card}>
                          <View style={styles.button}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.state.data.videoUrls[4].eventName}</Text> // Here, I'm getting error which is shown below image
                          </View>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                          <View style={styles.button}>
                            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./school.jpg')} />
                          </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
                );
               return(
                  <View/>
               )
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna use it to show data in Rows you can do something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        ''
    ]),
  }
}
```

...

```
.then((responseData) => {    
    var arrayOutput=[];
    arrayOutput.push(responseData);
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(arrayOutput),
    });
})
```

If you just want to save the array to do something else

```
.then((responseData) => {    
    var arrayOutput=[];
    arrayOutput.push(responseData);
    this.setState({
        saveArray: arrayOutPut,
    });
})
```

And then the array will be saved on the this.state.saveArray and you can use it when you want.

Comment: Thanks @Brunaine. But i'm not working on row.. Still i'll appreciate the answer.

Comment: But the second part i showed you how you save the all object you just need then to access it , like test.name if im not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks both of you.